# Find near date from current date in multiple dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I Have three dates:

`25/10/2012`,`01/01/2013`,`26/12/2012`.

How can i find which is nearest date from current date in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Is it a single string or in table format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this!!

```
DECLARE @today DATE = '2013-10-25';

 SELECT MAX(foo_date) AS prior_date FROM tables
         WHERE foo_date <= @today
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want

```
select top 1 * from your_table
order by abs(datediff(day, date_column, getdate()))
```

Comment: I think you missed first parameter in datediff function.`datediff(day, date_column, getdate())`